# Override or extend function of a contributed module

Tags: 8, hooks

i need to modify the submit function of the module **custom_search** *(8.x-1.0-beta3)*.

I need to set a **Cookie** every time the **guest user** search something, how can i override or extend the submit function?

It looks like not represent a **hook**. The function is: **custom_search_search_page_submit** located in the file *custom_search.module* and called by the **custom_search_form_alter** function that implements **hook_form_alter()**

```
/**
 * Search pages settings form callback.
 */
function custom_search_search_page_submit($form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $pageId = $form_state->getValue('id');
  // Save settings, and path as well so we can use it to retrieve the correct settings later.
  \Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('custom_search.settings.results')->set($pageId . '.path', $form_state->getValue('path')) 
    ->set($pageId . '.search', $form_state->getValue('custom_search_search'))
    ->set($pageId . '.advanced.visibility', $form_state->getValue('custom_search_advanced_search'))
    ->set($pageId . '.advanced.collapsible', $form_state->getValue('custom_search_collapsible'))
    ->set($pageId . '.advanced.collapsed', $form_state->getValue('custom_search_collapsed'))
    ->set($pageId . '.advanced.criteria', $form_state->getValue('custom_search_criteria'))
    ->set($pageId . '.advanced.types', $form_state->getValue('custom_search_types'))
    ->set($pageId . '.advanced.languages', $form_state->getValue('custom_search_languages'))
    ->set($pageId . '.info', $form_state->getValue('custom_search_info'))
    ->set($pageId . '.filter.position', $form_state->getValue('custom_search_filter_position'))
    ->set($pageId . '.filter.label', $form_state->getValue('custom_search_filter_label'))
    ->set($pageId . '.filter.any', $form_state->getValue('custom_search_filter_any'))
    ->save();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up with the next code on my own module, thanks to @4k4 and @marcvangend 
It works like a charm!!

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Bring customizations to the default core functions
 *
 */
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime;

 /**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function my_module_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'search_form') {
    $form['#submit'][] = 'my_module_search_page_submit';
  }
}

function my_module_search_page_submit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form_values = $form_state->getValues();
  $date = new DrupalDateTime();
  user_cookie_save(['search_form-'.$date->format('Y-m-d_H-i-s') => $form_values['keys'] ]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to override the submit function. Each module or theme can do exactly the same as the custom search module does. Use a form alter hook and add their own submit function to the form array. On submit they are each executed one after another.

**mymodule.module**

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'form_id') {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_search_page_submit';
  }
}

function mymodule_search_page_submit($form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  // set cookie
}
```

Comment: I need to create a new module? Or i can place the above code somewhere in my theme?

Comment: This belongs in a custom module. It's best to maintain the separation between code that controls how your site works (modules) and code that controls how your site looks (theme).

Comment: @LeninMeza: This works both in modules and themes. In a theme you put the code in `mytheme.theme`. I agree with marcvangend, a module is the better place.